# iOS Game Crash - [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I get the following error in Xcode console:

**2017-09-06 19:30:18.716705+0300 App Name [872:246266] [RevMob] Starting RevMobAds
2017-09-06 19:30:18.733652+0300 App Name[872:246266] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-09-06 19:30:18.734925+0300 App Name[872:246266] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
2017-09-06 19:30:19.161180+0300 App Name[872:246266] Flurry: Starting session on Agent Version [Flurry_iOS_199_8.1.0]
(lldb)**

App crash on App Start. On the device, I see only the splash screen or launch image, nothing else. None of the third party SDKs are causing issues since I tested and removed them one by one, but the issue persisted.

This is a slots game, it does not use the Photo Gallery to use 
Privacy - Camera Usage Description and Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description to cause this error in info.plist. Clearly, that's not the case.

Here's a screenshot in Xcode to emphasize this issue in more details:

[image: iOS Game Crash]